# How to resolve this - Failed to collect dependencies at org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.4

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.howtodoinjava:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.postgresql:postgresql:pom:42.2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.4/postgresql-42.2.4.pom: Unknown host No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Make sure you have all the required jars added in your project classpath or has entry in pom.xml

Comment: `No such host is known`: You have a networking problem on your end.

Comment: common things to verify: can you access that site in your browser? are using any VPN that is restricting your code to resolve that host? What is your repo host in pom file? Are you using a settings file in your .m2 folder that has repo host and somehow repo.maven.apache.org is not allowed to be accessed? Is your code behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Share your `pom.xml` and `application.properties`, anyway it should be something like:

- Pom file

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

- Application peroperies

```yaml
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdatabasename
spring.datasource.username=postgres (this is default username)
spring.datasource.password=yourpassword

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```